# Show that $T:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ and $S: \Bbb{R} \times (\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}) \to \Bbb{R}$ are continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I need to show that the functions $T:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ and $S: \Bbb{R} \times (\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}) \to \Bbb{R}$ given by $T(x,y)=xy$ and $S(x,y)=x/y$  are continuous functions. Both $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{R}$ are equipped with the standard topology.

For $T$ I took an open subset  $(x,y) \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ and I try to show that $$T^{-1}((x,y)) = \{(a,b):a \in \Bbb{R}, b\in (\tfrac xa, \tfrac ya)\}$$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Will appreciate any help

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are continuous then $fg$ is continuous. Can you show $f(x,y)=x$ is continuous?

Comment: Do you really need to this the hard way? Using the definition from calculus (instead of topology) would be much simpler.

Comment: And did you try anything?

Comment: yes $a\in\Bbb{R}$, fixed it.
I cant show that the reverse image is open

Comment: You may consider preimages of open sets.

Comment: @openspace what do you mean?

Comment: Note you are implicitly assuming $a>0$ in your expression for $T^{-1}((x,y))$... Using this type of expression, we would need to consider the cases of $a<0$ and $a=0$ separately.

Comment: @Integrand that actually sounds easier than what I wanted to do. thanks!
But will it work with S as well? how?

Comment: Your approach works. Any open set in $\mathbb R$ can be written as a union of open intervals after all. You will have to distinguish cases for $a$ though. It matters if $a$ is positive, negative, or zero. It can be simplified by following @Integrand's suggestion to avoid distinguishing cases.

Comment: @Integrand  how can I show that fg is continuous?
Its true in $\Bbb{R}$ but is it true in any topological space?

Comment: @BrianMoehring you rigth. So if we assume a>0 how can I show its an open subset?

Comment: "how can I show that fg is continuous? Its true in $\mathbb{R}$ but is it true in any topological space?" -- Note products aren't even defined in every topological space.  The space needs to have algebraic structure which is compatible with the topology, e.g. topological groups, topological rings, etc.

Comment: @BrianMoehring so I can't realy use it in here

Comment: "So if we assume a>0 how can I show its an open subset?" -- I'm not sure this is the most efficient, but if e.g. $(a,b) \in T^{-1}((x,y))$ for $a,b \neq 0$ then we may assume $0 \not\in (x,y)$.  Then you need to find some $\varepsilon$ such that $0 < \varepsilon < \min(|a|, |b|)$ and $$x < (a\pm_1\varepsilon)(b\pm_2\varepsilon) < y$$

Comment: "so I can't realy use it in here" -- I didn't say that.  I was speaking directly to your question of "is it true in any topological space?"  Any method you use will require you to utilize properties of $\mathbb{R}$.  Your proof will not generalize to every topological space or even every metric space.

Comment: @BrianMoehringb how can I found that ε? and what if a=0? so I get  a close subset $\{(0,b):b\in \Bbb{R}\}$   (I need also $0\in (x,y))$
But than the union isn't open

Answer (score 1):

*Continuity of $T$.*

Let $(x,y)$ be any point of $\Bbb R^2$ and $\varepsilon<1$ be any positive number. Pick positive $\delta<\varepsilon(1 \max\{x,y\})^{-1}$. Let $(x’,y’)$ be any point of $\Bbb R^2$ such that $|x’-x|<\delta$ and $|y’-y|<\delta$. Then

$$|x’y’-xy|\le |x’y’-x’y|+|x’y-xy|=|x’||y’-y|+|y||x’-x|<(|x|+1)\delta+|y|\delta\le 2\varepsilon.$$

*Continuity of $S$.*

Define a map  $f: \Bbb{R} \times (\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\})\to\Bbb R^2$, $(x,y)\mapsto (x,1/y)$. Since $S=Tf$ and the map $T$ is continuos, it suffices  to show that the map $f$  is continuous.

Let $(x,y)$ be any point of $\Bbb{R} \times (\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\})\to\Bbb R^2$ and $\varepsilon<1$ be any positive number. Pick positive $\delta<\min\left\{\varepsilon,\left|\tfrac y2\right|,
|y|^2\varepsilon\right\}$. Let $(x’,y’)$ be any point of $\Bbb R^2$ such that $|x’-x|<\delta$ and $|y’-y|<\delta$. Then $|y’|\ge \tfrac {|y|}2$, so

$$\left|\frac 1{y’}-\frac 1{y}\right|=\left|\frac{y-y’}{yy’}\right|=\frac{|y-y’|}{|yy’|}\le\frac {2\delta}{|y|^2}\le2\varepsilon.$$